# write a function to calculate the range of every five observations using R

Tags: r

Write a function that calculates the average and range of every five observations in the dataset?  If the number of values in the last group of numbers is less than 5 it needs to gives a note about it.
For example if the data are 3,4,5,6,7,2,3,4,5,6,6,1
The function should return:
The average and range of (3,4,5,6,7)
and average and range of (2,3,4,5,6) 
and average and range for (6,1) and
a message that in the last group you have only 2 values.

Hi here is my question, i know how to write a function to calculate the average and range, but i don't know how to give every five observations?

How to do these?

Thanks.

Comment: Show us your code. And label your question according to programming language

Comment: I changed the tag to the appropriate language (R), so more relevant members will see it. I also suggest posting what you have attempted so far.

Comment: Thanks for changing the tag, i just began to learn R language, not really familiar with the language. I just know to write a function is like average<-function() and range<-function() but i don't know how to write the commands.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using **base R**

Data

```
dat <- c(3,4,5,6,7,2,3,4,5,6,6,1)
```

Create indicator for every 5 observations. Look at `?rep` to see what the arguments `each` and `length` do

```
(grp <- rep(1:length(dat), each=5, length=length(dat)))
#  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3
```

Calculate statistics: where n indicates the number (n) of each observations used to calculate the statistics

```
by(dat , list(group=grp) , function(i) c(mean=mean(i),
                                         min=min(i),
                                         max=max(i),
                                         n = length(i)))
```

Note: you can substitute the function `aggregate` for the `by` function to produce a data.frame as the output.

Answer (score 0):

this is a `plyr` solution. You could output a warning based on the `ct` column. I think that the act of summarizing and the warning should be kept separate, so I have not included that here.

```
> library(plyr)
> dat<-data.frame(c1=c(3,4,5,6,7,2,3,4,5,6,6,1))
> dat$grp<-with(dat, cumsum(1==rep(1:5, length=length(c1))))
> ddply(dat, .(grp), summarize, mean=mean(c1),min=min(c1), max=max(c1), ct=length(c1))
  grp mean min max ct
1   1  5.0   3   7  5
2   2  4.0   2   6  5
3   3  3.5   1   6  2
```

Comment: Sorry I missed something, my dataset is the previous answer, which asked for the function of prime no. I don't know how to write the function of every five observations of the function.

Comment: And sorry what's the meaning of plyr and ct?

Comment: sorry I don't quite understand your first question. This calculates mean, min/max (i.e. your ranges) and the number (ct) of observations in each group (i.e. every 5, the first 5 are group 1, the next 5 group 2 etc). `plyr` is a package for R. A quick google search should give you more info

Comment: My question to write a function that calculates the average and range of every five observations in the dataset? If the number of values in the last group of numbers is less than 5 it needs to gives a note about it. The data set c(3,4,5,6,7,2,3,4,5,6,6,1). Thanks very much.

Comment: Yes, this does that. You're just responsible for adding in an extra line that would check the values of column `ct` and if there are any < 5 then output the warning message...

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is a *rolling* function. Have a look at this [link](https://www.inkling.com/read/r-cookbook-paul-teetor-1st/chapter-14/recipe-14-12).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, maybe simpler for you if you are new to R :

```
average5=function(vector_data){
  # transform data into dataframe
  df=data.frame(a=vector_data)
  #create new column class  
  df$class=ceiling(1:(nrow(df))/5)

  # calculate mean by class
  average=aggregate(a~class,data=df,FUN='mean')

  # test if number of rows is a multiple of 5
  # keep only the second column and transform it into a vector
  if (nrow(df)%%5==0){
    average=average$a
  } else {
    #remove last class
    average=average$a[1:(nrow(average)-1)] 
    cat("Last group has only",nrow(df)%%5,"values \n")
  }
  return(average)
}
```

The output gives :

```
> test=c(3,4,5,6,7,2,3,4,5,6,6,1)
> average5(test)
 Last group has only 2 values 
 [1] 5 4
```

Comment: Is it the ouput you wanted ? Can you tell me where you don't understand the code ? You can try to paste the code inside the function into R to see how it works, line by line.